# FitNesse: Show image with dynamic source

Tags: c#, fitnesse

I have a method that returns the path to an image, and I want to show that image in the test output.

Is this possible?

```
!|script             |Image             |
|# Url() returnes "http://files/img.jpg"|
|$img=               |Url               |

# I want to see the image at http://files/img.jpg
$img

# Does fitnesse support any templating so that I can do
<img src="$img" />
```

I'm using FitNesse with FitSharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render an image directly from a URL as far as I know. BUT you can have your fixture return an image to be included in the HTML output.

If you add a method `Image()` which returns `"<div><img src\"" + Url() + "\"/></div>"` your script can become:

```
!|script             |Image             |
|show                |Image             |
```

You can see an example of this in action (using Java Slim) in the rows using the `take screenshot` command of my fixtures in https://fhoeben.gitlab.io/-/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/-/jobs/2569203409/artifacts/example-results/example-test-1/HsacExamples.SlimTests.BrowserTests.ScriptTest.html

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: I switched to using GitLab, see https://gitlab.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/-/jobs/artifacts/master/file/example-results/example-test-1/HsacExamples.SlimTests.BrowserTests.ScriptTest.html?job=example-reports-combine